# How to handle approach from company B while being almost hired in company A?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, hiring-process

A couple of weeks ago I was approached by company A, by offering me an exciting opportunity. 
I was really pleased and I managed to make it to the last/final interview with them. 
So far all good, till a couple of days before my final interview, I was approached by a **really** great company named B, offering me an even greater opportunity. 
I find what company B does more exciting and more important/meaningful for the society. 
Also, compensation is by far greater which excites me as this would be my first job after my graduation and internship.

My first informal/briefing call with company B happens the same day I am having my last interview with company A. I suspect (if i do well) that company A will be offering me the job and probably asking for my commitment in some way.

**Supposedly I prefer B over A, what is the best approach that I can take here**?
e.g. 
 - *tell A to give me a couple of days to consider it...while at the same time tell B to "hurry up" ?*

**Any ideas on how I can handle this situation, without being impolite to anyone, or risking my initial opportunity?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If company A makes an offer, make sure it's in writing first and all the details of the offer are fully worked out before you actually accept it. This includes seeing the employee handbook if the contract mentions it.

And don't just tell company B to hurry up, tell them that you have another company that will probably make you an offer very soon. But do not give them the name of that company A, you do not want them colluding with each other.

If company B asks for the name of company A, give them a very general description of the company A, but nothing more. If they don't believe you about that other company A, that's fine too. They do not need to believe you. Either they believe you, or they don't. Either they want to hire you, or they don't. It's just that if they really want to hire you, they'll have to hurry up.

Comment: Getting an offer is they key.  AND making sure you meet all the conditions of employment.